# Rank of dual sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $F$ be a coherent sheaf on some scheme $X$. The rank of $F$ at $x$ is the dimension of the $k(x)$-vector space $F_x\otimes_{O_{X,x}} k(x)$ (ie the fibre of $F$ at $x$). It is clear that if $F$ is locally free, then the dual $F^*$ has the same rank as $F$ at every point $x$. **I'm wondering if the converse is also true, ie that if a sheaf $F$ is such that the dual has the same rank at every point, then $F$ must be locally free?** I tried some simple examples (maybe there is a counterexample), but the ones I have don't work (eg the ideal sheaf $F$ of a point $x\in\mathbf{A}^2$ has rank $1$ at every point in $\mathbf{A}^2-x$, while it has rank $2$ at $x$; on the other hand the dual is a line bundle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the example of the sheaf $F$ on $\mathbb{A}^3$ defined by the exact sequence
$$
0 \to F \to \mathcal{O}^{\oplus 3} \stackrel{(x,y,z)}\longrightarrow \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O}_o \to 0,
$$
where the last term is the structure sheaf of the origin.

Comment: Ah yes, cute example, thanks! More generally, let $F$ be a reflexive sheaf of rank $2$. Then $F^*\simeq F\otimes(\mathrm{det} \ F)^*$, in particular $F$ is self-dual if the determinant is trivial, as in this case.